How to solve " Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded",ChunkLoadError at __webpack_require__.f.j in Angular 13 project
We are using angular 13 with microfrontend architecture.
After clearing cache ,cookies ,all browsing data,we are getting chunk load error and maximum stack overflow error.once we hard reload,its working fine.
Error
Any solution for this?
wanted to login in the first time itself

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
